# Entity Framework - grab stored procedure result

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
    @sampleParam1 VARCHAR (10)
AS     
    DECLARE @AccountID INT      

    --some business logic that evaluates value of @AccountID    
    SELECT @AccountID --I want to grab this value in .Net application.
```

I am executing this stored procedure using .Net like this:

```
class MyResult
{
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
}

public void myfun()
{
      myEntitesEntites = new MyEntites();//Using EF6

      var result = myEntitesEntites.Database.SqlQuery<MyResult>
     ("exec [dbo].[myProc] @sampleParam1", new SqlParameter("sampleParam1", "20161028"))
}
```

I was expecting `result.AccountID` will hold value of last `SELECT @AccountID` statement in the stored procedure. But `result.AccountID` is always 0.

**Note**: When I am executing same stored procedure from SSMS I can see actual value of `@AccountID` which is not 0.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change the your stored procedure

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
       @sampleParam1 VARCHAR (10)
   AS     
      DECLARE @AccountID INT  =    @sampleParam1
      --some business logic that evaluates value of @AccountID    
      SELECT @AccountID as AccountID --I want to grab this value in .Net application.

   public void myfun()
   {
        myEntitesEntites = new MyEntites();//Using EF6

        var result = myEntitesEntites.Database.SqlQuery<MyResult>
    ("exec [dbo].[myProc] @sampleParam1", new SqlParameter("sampleParam1", "20161028"))
   }
   ```

   Name of column from result stored procedure  must match with name same as properties from a object.
2. The your procedure `[dbo].[myProc]` returns an `int` value

So for example you can change type of return parameter on int. In this case the method `SqlQuery` will return correct value the variable @AccountID from the stored procedure.

```
    public MyResult myfun()
    {
         myEntitesEntites = new MyEntites();//Using EF6

         int accountID =  myEntitesEntites.Database.SqlQuery<int>
     ("exec [dbo].[myProc] @sampleParam1", new SqlParameter("sampleParam1", "20161028"))
         return new MyResult()
                    {
                       AccountID = accountID
                    } 
    }
```

Comment: Bingo @Alexcei Shmakov.  Thanks.

Comment: HI, how can we fetch back multiple columns? like if last line of stored procedure was 'SELECT @Field1 , @Field2'?  Will I have to create a class which has two fields named 'Field1' and 'Field2'?  I tried doing that but not working.

Comment: After modifying SP as suggested by you it worked! But, unfortunately I can't modify SP which is already used by several clients so will need to find some other workaround.  Thanks for your help.